# Number values are saved as strings in firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I use this function to send data to firestore

```
exports.professional = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();

    const userId: string = request.body['userId'];
    const qualificationId: number = request.body['qualificationId'];
    const occupationId: number = request.body['occupationId'];
    const employmentType: EMPLOYMENT_TYPE = request.body['employmentType'];
    const collegeOrInstitution: string = request.body['collegeOrInstitution'];

    return db.collection('profiles').doc(userId)
        .set(
        {
            professional: {
                qualifaicationId: qualificationId,
                occupationId: occupationId,
                employmentType: employmentType,
                collegeOrInstitution: collegeOrInstitution
            }
        },
        {
            merge: true
        }).then(writeResult => {
           return response.json(
                {
                    status: 1,
                    message: 'Professional details saved successfully',
                    result: userId
                }
            )
        });
});
```

I have declared some variables as number but when i check the firestore doc,
it is saved as strings. please see the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

In the code, i have declared `occupationId` as a number variable but after it is saved it is a string, again please see the screenshot. Anyone know why it is changing data types?

Comment: `const occupationId: number` --- the type declaration does not convert the actual data. If you need numbers you need to explicitly use the `Number()` function.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @zerkms , that worked. please post that as an answer, so that i can check that as an answer

Comment: any reason behind this, still not clear why its changing the data type of value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declarations, e.g.:

```
const occupationId: number
```

by themselves do not convert passed data in case if the assignment type is `any` (it's done so that it was possible to gradually switch from js to ts).

If you need to have a number explicitly - you need to use something that converts the actual value type for you.

One possible way to do that:

```
const occupationId: number = Number(request.body['occupationId']);
```

References:

- [MDN: `Number` - Convert numeric strings to numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_to_numbers)

Comment: I use javascript, const floatPrice = Number.parseFloat(price).toFixed(2); and using price: floatPrice, in the collection set. But it is not working

Answer (score 2):

When you set the value for the object, you have to check whether the value is a valid number or letter, if it's a valid number then you have to convert it to a correct number format else you just need to pass the variable as it is.

```
+value || value
```

Example:

```js
const apple = "Apple"
const amount = "5"
const getRealValue = (val) => +val || val

console.log(getRealValue(apple))
console.log(getRealValue(amount))

console.log(typeof getRealValue(apple))
console.log(typeof getRealValue(amount))
```

In this way you can let the Firestore understand your data type, this process can be done for all of your object variables as iterating through `Object.keys`