# Update Firestore document causes field boolean type to change to string

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I started this firestore document manually from the console specifying enabled as a boolean type.
I'm building now more of the constructs to update it in angular see below code.

```
  activateMenuItem(venueId: string, menuId: string, menuItemId, enabled: boolean) {
    const update = {
      'enabled': false
    };

    update.enabled = enabled;
    const db = this.firestore.firestore;
    from(db.collection('venues')
      .doc(venueId)
      .collection('menus')
      .doc(menuId)
      .collection('items')
      .doc(menuItemId)
      .update(update))
      .subscribe(value => {
        console.log("On next");
      }, (error) => {
        console.log("on error" + error);
      });
  }
```

This is all working properly, however when I set the field enabled to the boolean value, the field type changes to a string afterwards.

Before

[image: Before with right data type]

After

[image: After with wrong data type]

Additional code on how its being invoked.

```
  onChange(enabled) {
    console.log("Changing " + enabled);
    this.service.activateMenuItem(this.venueId, this.menuId, this.menuItemId, enabled);
  }
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to share the code that illustrates how you are seeing a string instead of a boolean?  We should be able to duplicate the issue based on what you provide.

Comment: There isn't any additional code to show how it looks afterwards, it is showing the wrong type of fieldtype afterwards in the portal.  I think I answered the question myself though I'm a little fuzzy on why I had to do what I did.

Comment: I added pictures of the portal to better explain it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was modified in conversation with commenter.
The real answer has more to do with the following.

```
  onChange(enabled) {
    console.log("Changing " + enabled);

    this.service.activateMenuItem(this.venueId, this.menuId, this.menuItemId, enabled);
  }
```

It looks like as I'm sending this field down as a boolean the type information was still a `string`.

<s>I found a [similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795490/number-values-are-saved-as-strings-in-firestore) to this shortly afterwards which has a workable solution.</s>

Apparently calling it an `enabled` type was not enough.  I needed to make it a Boolean object.

Doing this ensured the firestore document maintained its previous data type.

```
    const update = {
      'enabled': false
    };

    update.enabled = Boolean(enabled);
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary.  A normal JS boolean has always worked fine.

Comment: I would agree it shouldn't be required but consistently reproduces.   Agree something is wrong, but I'm not sure what else to look at.

Comment: @DougStevenson so you're right I've added additional code to above question.  It was really how I was passing the enabled parameter in the first place.  I had assumed this was coming as a boolean but now looking at its still in string form so this has little to do with firestore document updates and more to do with general typescript.